# Since when do the POSIX and GNU rm not delete /?

Tags: rm, posix, history, gnu

For several years now, the GNU `rm` utility won't delete `/` unless it is called with the `--no-preserve-root` option. However, the command `rm -rf /` has been lodged in the collective subconscious as dangerous for a very long time and people still often cite it as a "scary" command.

I was wondering when this rule that `rm` cannot delete `/` first appeared. I checked the POSIX specs, and I can see that while [POSIX:2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html) includes this safety feature, [POSIX:2001](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/rm.html) does not. Since the online versions of the POSIX specs are updated from time to time, with each new sub-release, I also checked the wayback machine and found the [relevant page of POSIX:2008 from 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20101228015157/http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html) and was able to confirm that the rule that `rm` cannot remove `/` was already listed then.

So, my questions are:

- When was the rule that `rm` cannot remove `/` added to the POSIX specs? Was it in the original 2008 edition of the Single UNIX Specification version 4 or was it added in a revision?
- When was this limitation added to GNU `rm`? I'm pretty sure it was before it was added to POSIX, but when did it happen?

Comment: See also [Does 'rm .\*' ever delete the parent directory?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/90073)

Comment: Related: [Austin Group Interpretation #019](https://collaboration.opengroup.org/austin/interps/documents/4202/AI-019.txt) (2003), which described (but did not implement) the change.

Comment: 2003-11-09 https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commit;h=34e3ea055721ecc72e6f636700e8ba7b58069c65

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can find the HTML version of all the editions of POSIX 2008 online:

- original: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/rm.html
- TC1 (2013 edition) http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2013edition/utilities/rm.html
- TC2 (2016 edition) http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/rm.html

That was added in the 2008 edition.

Technical corrigenda generally don't add new features.

You can see the previous version (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/rm.html) (POSIX 2004) didn't have that text.

The new text was accepted in the [2003-05-09 austin group conference](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/docs/austin_168.txt) for inclusion in a later revision of the standard.

It was [requested by John Beck of Sun Microsystems in March that same year](https://collaboration.opengroup.org/operational/mailarch.php?action=show&archive=austin-group-l&num=5044&sophscript=N) (link requires opengroup registration, see also [Enhancement Request Number 5 here](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/aardvark/finaltext/xcubug.txt)).

> John Beck  wrote, on Tue 11 Mar 2003:
>
> ```
> @ page 820 line 31681-31683 section rm comment {JTB-1}
>
> Problem:
>
> Defect code :  3. Clarification required
>
> An occasional user mistake, with devastating consequences, is to
> write a shell script with a line such as:
>       rm -rf $VARIABLE1/$VARIABLE2
> or
>       rm -rf /$VARIABLE1
> without verifying that either variable is set, which can lead to
>       rm -rf /
> being the resulting command.  Since there is no plausible
> circumstance under which this is the desired behavior, it seems
> reasonable to disallow this.  Such a safeguard would, however,
> violate the current specification.
>
> Action:
>
> Either extend the exceptions for . and .. on the noted lines
> to list / as well, or specify that the behavior of rm if an
> operand resolves to / is undefined.
> ```

GNU `rm` added `--preserve-root` and `--no-preserve-root` options in [this 2003-11-09 commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commit;h=34e3ea055721ecc72e6f636700e8ba7b58069c65), but `--preserve-root` only became the default in [this 2006-09-03 commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commit;h=89ffaa19909d31dffbcf12fb4498afb72666f6c9), so in coreutils 6.2

FreeBSD has been *preserving slash* since [that 2004-10-04 commit](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=136113) (with a *"Find out how flame-proof my underwear really is"* commit log), but [initially not when under `POSIXLY_CORRECT`](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=136124), until they remembered to check a decade later that POSIX was now mandating it [at which point it was done also in POSIX mode](https://reviews.freebsd.org/D4092).

The FreeBSD initial commit mentions Solaris was already doing it at that time.

@JdePB  (in comment below) found that [link to a Sun insider story](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8896812) corroborating and giving more details on the Solaris origin and suggesting Solaris already had the safeguard in place before they made the request to the Austin group.

It explains the rationale for adding that exclusion. While one can only blame oneself if they do `rm -rf /`, there's a case where a script could do it if doing `rm -rf -- "$1/$2"` without checking that `$1`/`$2` were provided which is the thing that hit some Sun customers bad when misapplying a Solaris patch (according to that link).

[The forbidding of deletion of `.` and `..` was added long before that](/q/90073) and again to safeguard against potential mishaps. `rm` still is a dangerous command. It does what it's meant to do: remove what you tell it to.

```
rm -rf /*
cd /tmp &&  rm -rf .*/   # on some systems where rm -rf ../ still removes
                         # the content of ../ and shells that still
                         # may include . and .. in glob expansions.
rm -rf -- "$diretcory"/* # note the misspelled variable name
dir='foo '; rm -rf $dir/*
```

Would also remove everything. Shell filename completion has been known to cause such problems when you do

```
rm -rf someth<Tab>/*
```

Expanded to:

```
rm -rf something /*
```

Because `something` so happened not to be a directory.

Shells like `tcsh` or `zsh` will add an extra prompt when trying to call `rm` with a `*` wildcard (`tcsh` not by default).

Comment: [Bryan Cantrill tells a story about this.](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8896812)  See also https://superuser.com/questions/742334/ and https://superuser.com/questions/542978/ .

Comment: As a young co-op SA, I tried erasing the hidden files in a user's directory on SunOS w/ `rm -rf .*` from his home dir. Shortly after, all the phone lines lit up...

Comment: I bet $ rm -rf .* = rm -rf / in a convoluted way to get there.

Comment: @GuruAdrian sure,  * means match everything so   .* = .filename but also ../ and therefore ../.. and ../../.. ad infinatum until you run out of bitspace for the command.

Comment: maybe in modern shells. It wasn't always that way. I left that depth of system administration and development more than 15 years ago

Comment: @Guru, yes those `!(...)` patterns come from ksh (ksh88, ksh86a didn't have them), they're enabled with `set -o kshglob` in `zsh` (`zsh` also has its own (more usable if you ask me) extensions, and zsh like pdksh or fish already do the right thing when it comes to . and .. in globs). With ksh, you get an _interesting_ outcome if you do `FIGNORE='!(..)' ksh -c 'echo rm -rf */*'`